# firebase deploying a web site "Page not found"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a web application that I deployed on firebase, I used npm and the tools it offers for website deployment management. the problem is that the deployment is done wonderfully but when i open the website, the site loads very well and after some time, the website tells me "page not found" please someone can help me help to understand what is happening or to fix this error?

the deployment is done very well but when I try to browse firebase I get the message "Page not found"

Help me please

firebase web site, error
[Page not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mup8W.png) [deploying capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNVPb.png)